# How can I create a class diagram with NetBeans' 6.8 UML module?

Tags: uml, netbeans6.8, class-diagram

It seems to me the UML module of NetBeans is a bit too much hidden. In NetBeans 6.5 it was very easy to create an UML diagram. No plugin installation necessary or sth. like. 
Read [my post](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/where-is-uml-for-netbeans-6-8/) where I found a zip file to install the UML module.

And now, after this procedure, I got the UML module back, but it seems to me that I cannot create class diagram with it. Do you know how I can do this with NetBeans 6.8?

**Update1**: There seems to be no support

**Update2**: Nevertheless [somebody](http://amitmisra.wordpress.com/2010/01/30/netbeans-6-8-uml-support/) seems to got it working.

Comment: yeah I agree, much easier on earlier versions, even 6.7

Comment: The UML plugin is no longer supported in new versions of NetBeans.  Not sure why, but that seems to be the case, does not answer your question, but it does put it in context.  I could be just slowly breaking.

Comment: @Karussell It is two years since your original post.  Do you know if there has been any new UML or Class Diagram support in Netbeans 7.*?

Comment: there is still no support for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converted to answer: The UML plugin is no longer supported in new versions of NetBeans as stated in the wiki http://wiki.netbeans.org/UML. Not sure why, but that seems to be the case, does not answer your question, but it does put it in context. I could be just slowly breaking which is why both you and the blogger you linked to can't gets things to work.

Comment: Hmmh, yes I know. But I would like to get it working... :-( BTW: the blogger, its me ;-) I updated the text accordingly

Comment: You are right. See here for the bug report https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=178646

Comment: But someone had success with 6.8

http://amitmisra.wordpress.com/2010/01/30/netbeans-6-8-uml-support/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Paradigm has released a community edition for UML 7.2 which is free for non-commercial use.
You can find it at http://www.visual-paradigm.com/download/vpuml.jsp?edition=ce. You have to register for an activation key though!

Comment: -1, not really related to the question ... there are several free uml designers out, such as eclipse, argouml etc

Comment: Sorry, but i thought the UML module was discontinued in the default distribution of Netbeans after 6.5 and instead they now recommend visual paradigm(VP), and it is quite easy to create class diagrams with VP.!

Comment: ah, I see. sorry! please update the answer so that I can undo my -1 vote :-)

Answer (score 1):

cant add comment :-( but just want to confirm what DCraft said:

the community edition of Visual Paradigm does not support forward or reverse engineering.

seems the only solution is to use an older version of netbeans

Answer (score 1):

With the current 7.2 Netbeans release the capability for UML Sequence  and class diagram creation exists with the Visual Paradigm UML tool (version 10). You can get the trial version for 30 days that will do the reverse engineering from the code. Here is a link to the instructions. http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/2381/2384/66565_reverseengin.html ( The community version has this feature but it is disabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you go [here](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/6.9/rc/zip.html) and download the `UML` module cluster you can simply copy it into the NetBeans install directory and then NetBeans will have UML functionality again!

If you don't feel like looking through the page of module clusters the direct download link is [here](http://javascript:%20download_file('zip/moduleclusters/netbeans-6.9rc2-201005312001-ml-uml.zip')).

Comment: Is reverse engineering from java source working? (e.g. to produce class diagrams)

Comment: Yes it is, I have tested it in NetBeans on Ubuntu (version 6.8) and Windows (6.9.1).

Answer (score 0):

I have NB 6.9.1. I've installed the UML plugin but it fails to make reverse engineering (create UML class diagram from existing source).
I didn't want to downgrade to 6.7, so I installed ArgoUML tool.
In order to generate class diagram from existing source you need to follow next steps:

**1.** File->Import Sources

**2.** Change the Files of Types to "All Files"

**3.** Select the directory (where the *.java files are stored) or packages

**4.** A small dialog window pop up -> select OK

**5.** On the left hand side, you will see UntitledModel. Click on the _classes and they should occur in right in the diagram as little boxes.

**6.** To show the attributes/methods, point a class (in the diagram), right click the mouse, select Show->"Show All Compartment"

Answer (score 0):

I am using a SDE-NB visual paradigm