# NetBeans 6.8/6.7 UML Class Diagrams

Tags: java, class, netbeans, uml, diagram

i have tried to generate Class Diagrams in NetBeans 6.7 and 6.8 but all i get is:

[image]

i figured out installing UML for 6.8 here: [NetBeans 6.8 UML](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/where-is-uml-for-netbeans-6-8/)

i have followed the instructions here: [UML Class diagrams](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702174016/http://forums.netbeans.org:80/post-55024.html)

i so far i failed to generate anything meaningful.

i have followed the tips:

Open your project, then create a new UML project (choose "Reverse Engineered Java-Platform model"). After that all your classes will be available in the UML project under "Model". You can now create a new class diagram and drag your classes from "Model" onto the diagram.

but nothing meaningful happens when i drag my classes to the Class Diagrams. it always represents the classes as "datatype" on the diagram and class info is not displayed.

any helpful tips regarding how can i fix this? or another way of generating Java class diagrams?

thank you for your time.

**EDIT: NetBeans 6.5.1 is working perfectly. thanks!**

Comment: I can reproduce your results, reverse engeneering seems broken. In earlier version it worked like described here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansUML

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127881/how-can-i-create-a-class-diagram-with-netbeans-6-8-uml-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127881/how-can-i-create-a-class-diagram-with-netbeans-6-8-uml-module) there is no solution for 6.7 try a lower version (e.g. 6.5) or try Visual Paradigm ... here is one snippet of a good comment:

*the UML module was discontinued in the default distribution of Netbeans after 6.5 and instead they now recommend visual paradigm(VP),*